# User are not allowed to logged-in in multiple device at a time

Tags: codeigniter

if a  user already login from chrome and user trying to login from firefox then system should automatically destroy first session which is created  from chrome.in codeigniter
please let me know how to solved this issue. and show me code

Comment: Hi Maulik, welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some more information to your question, and we'll try to help. Which version of CodeIgniter are you using? What have you tried so far? Have you written custom login code? Are you using a database for sessions?